# Why won't my weed whacker keep running?

Tags: lawn-mower, engine

I have a Husqvarna gas-powered weed whacker.  Starting late last season, it tends to die when given full throttle.  Now, it will start when on full choke or half choke, but once I put it in normal operating mode (after warmup) it dies.

It's using gasoline that has the oil mixed in, but the gasoline is rather old.  Could that be a factor?

Is there something I can do to fix this myself?

Comment: When was it last given a tuneup? Do you use fuel stabilizer?

Comment: Never, and no.  Engines and maintenance are a weakpoint in my skillset.  I'm currently in the process of looking for a service shop nearby.

Comment: This sounds like when I had some gas go bad, and the main jet ended up being clogged/covered with the film/shellac left by the bad gas. It would idle like a champ, the lean out when the throttle opened. Sounds like you're do for some carb cleaning time.

Comment: Never leave gas in a machine for extended periods. When you're going to store the machine, drain the fuel and run the machine dry. It sucks to waste gas, but it sucks even more when stale gas wrecks your equipment.

Comment: You can buy gas at some stations with no ethanol, and for small engines it's worth it.  Don't buy too much at a time either, it does get old.  In my part of the country BP stations have no ethanol gas in the gold handled pump.

Comment: @Tester101 Plus you don't have to be wasting that much gas - AIUI you can put half a gallon of gas+oil in a full car tank without causing problems for the car.

Comment: @Random832 I was a Boy Scout, I use old gas as kindling.

Comment: Depending on your usage it might make sense to buy a can of gas from a big box store.  It doesn't have ethanol and I found I use about one can each of the 2-stroke and 4-stroke(snowblower) in my non-lawnmower machines a year.  It is like 5x as much as at the pump but the convenience of it has been worthwhile.  I keep a 5 gallon can of regular gas for the lawnmower that magically seams to work with no maintenance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't take bad gas or ethanol to crud up tiny carb jets and orifices. Any gas gets old and any gas dries into varnish over time, especially that which has been mixed with two-stroke oil. Proper storage is critical.

Seek out an exploded diagram or a how-to and disassemble your carb. Make note of all screw settings (count turns to fully seated) and take some phone pics and clean everything thoroughly with solvent. It'll run better than new.

Comment: Do I need to drain the gas out before I try this?  I've never done anything to any engines beyond changing oil and filters, or air filters.

Comment: And what tools do I need?

Comment: I usually remove the tank and set it aside. Expect some dripping, so work over some towels and in a well-ventilated area.

Comment: Usually a #2 Phillips and some small wrenches. You haven't told us what you're working on.

Comment: Beware: carburetors are, at least to the non-pro, magic. If you disassemble and reassemble yours, you may find it not working and have no clue as to what has changed. Unless you're interested in learning the nitty-gritty, and don't mind if you spend a number of hours on the project, I'd leave it to a pro.

Comment: @isherwood exactly what do you need beyond "Husqvarna gas powered weed whacker"?

Comment: @DanielGriscom I probably will.  I don't particularly relish trying this kind of project on my own.  Although I DO understand their basic function - mix air and fuel to get the proper balance for combustion...

Comment: A model number is the typical requirement for any research.

Comment: @DanielGriscom You're right, of course, but the OP did post on a DIY forum. :)

Comment: @isherwood Still it doesn't hurt to tell them: you better not DIY in this case unless you're sure what to do :)

Comment: I think I'll be better off going to the shop.  Thanks all.

Comment: Great. Y'all scared him away. :P Even if you try and fail the repair is likely to cost about the same. There's little risk with trying.

Comment: I've noticed that the "carburators" keep getting flimsier and flimsier, and more and more expensive. Half of a splinter will clog it. If something breaks (like the mylar film that they use for gaskets) you can buy a whole carburator for less than any of the parts... but yeah, a small engine mechanics time costs even more! Oh, and this really pertains to Husqvarnas.

Comment: Could have tried a simpler approach at first - spray that thing down with a heavy dose of carburetor cleaner.

Comment: Carbs on small motors are one of the easiest things to repair. If you have not messed with the mixture screws count how many turns until closed tear them apart and clean. If the fuel pump is bad the home stores have a 3 pack for a couple of bucks, the fuel lines another couple of bucks that and possibly a new spark plug and carb cleaner is all it takes.

Answer (score 2):

I have had trouble with small motors since they added methanol to the fuel. the methanol breaks down many of the rubber seals and then the residue gets stuck in the carburetor filter screen. A can of carburetor cleaner and a few minutes to disassemble and cleaning may bring it back to new. Fresh gas is always a plus for small single piston motors.